# Hash for PE_HEADER

Tags: java, md5, portable-executable, antivirus

I'm working with scanning based on signature, read that PE-HEADER placed in 0x18 byte after PE (0x50 0x45) offsets. If I right understand it, that it is
[image]

On the basis of this segment creates MD5-hash(16 bytes)? And virus body (in the file) it is all file or not? How to find the virus in the infected file?

Comment: first I'd extract some binary data from virus, and check similiar pattern appearing in tested executable, hashing it is not exacly good idea because viruses tend to evolve in time.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk, as i know scanning based on the signature (hash MD5), uses only for PE (exe,dll etc) because hash can be calculated only for PE files based on the PE header and this type of scan allows you to determine the type of attack with high probability, without false positives.

Comment: There are many variants of same malware, your tool won't detect infected files (not counting original), so it may have no false positives but you wont catch 60% of malware

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk maybe, but it is not answer for my initial question

Comment: If it was an answer i would post an answer. Comments are *not* place for sharing answers, but comments

Comment: Question was how to find the virus in the infected file - i gave you an idea how to do it.